# SOAP webservice call using Spring integration framework

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration. I am trying to call soap webservice using Spring integration. I have webservice deployed at on my local server `http://localhost:8080/DemoWebService/tickets`.

Below are the configurations in Spring application context xml.

```
<int:gateway id="systemEntry" default-request-channel="requestChannel" default-reply-channel="responseChannel"
    service-interface="xpadro.spring.integration.ws.gateway.TicketService"/>
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="responseChannel" />
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="marshallingGateway"
    request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel"
    uri="http://localhost:8080/DemoWebService/tickets" marshaller="marshaller"
    unmarshaller="marshaller"/>
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="xpadro.spring.integration.ws.types" />
```

Below is the interface written as a gateway and a Junit test class.

```
public interface TicketService {

/**
 * Entry to the messaging system. All invocations to this method will be intercepted and sent to the SI "system entry" gateway
 * 
 * @param request
 */
@Gateway
public TicketResponse invoke(TicketRequest name );}
```

Code form Junit  test

```
@Test
public void testInvocation() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    TicketRequest request = new TicketRequest();
    request.setFilmId("aFilm");
    request.setQuantity(new BigInteger("3"));

    TicketResponse response = service.invoke(request);

    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEquals("aFilm",response.getFilmId());
    assertEquals(new BigInteger("5"), response.getQuantity());
}
```

But when I run the test , I am getting below error. Please help. Thanks..

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://ws.mkyong.com/}tickets has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Message part {http://www.xpadro.spring.samples.com/tickets}ticketRequest was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)
```

This service works well from SOAP UI.

am I missing anything here? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

> `Message part {http://www.xpadro.spring.samples.com/tickets}ticketRequest`

You should really compare what you send to that service from code and what from SOAP UI.

Looks like you don't use the proper `namespace` in your JaxB generated domain classes.

Looks like the real `namespace` must be `ws.mkyong.com`.

Out of topic: I know who is `xpadro` :-), but you really should be sure that you are consistent with WSDL.